# Syncing new/de-synced microservices in a pub-sub messaging system

Tags: architecture, microservices, messaging, publish-subscribe

As a contrived example, suppose I have a `Posts` service for a blog web application that contains all of the blog posts.  This co-exists with other services, say `Users` and `UserLikes`, and these services communicate through a pub-sub-based message broker.

The `UserLikes` service allows users to 'like' certain posts, and it maintains a list of active users to enforce consistency.  To do this, it subscribes to messages from the `Users` service for user creates/deletes/updates.

This all works well, but suppose now I want to add a `UserDislikes` service.  This service comes into place after the current users have been created, so it will not receive the current users as new user events from the `Users` service.  How should we go about syncing up this new service with the current user list?

My initial thought is to have the `Users` service periodically publish a list of all current user objects (say to S3), and publish this event to a `UserSync` topic.  However, the need to sync like this is rare, and moreover the export wouldn't be in response to the event of another service needing a full sync.  So what is the solution?  Perhaps a `UserSyncRequest` message topic that the `Users` service subscribes to and exports whenever another services asks for it?

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Example seems a little naive as the boundaries of "likes" and "dislikes" could potentially be the same service but I'll go along with the example :). The reason you've probably created a `UserLikes` and a `UserDislikes` service is probably because the user is valued less than the *likes* and *dislikes* in these services.

In that case, you can probably just save the *likes* and *dislikes* with a corresponding **user identifier** by publishing this information to the event bus when a like or dislike action has occurred. Now if you want to display a page or respond with user information along with the like, you'll just have to make two service calls, one to the user service and another to the "likes" or "dislikes" service.

Another potential solution you can look at instead of publishing just the corresponding user identifier is that you can publish the whole entire user object and write the user into the database for the `UserDislikes` service. Technically, in your "likes" services you don't care about the user until they have liked or disliked something so this will work fine. Again, for both solutions, you'll still need to subscribe to user created, updated and delete events.

Answer (score 0):

In your case first I would not maintain active users list in UserLike or UserDislike Service.

You are maintaining a list such that if a user is deleted then it should not be able to like a Post.

In 99 % or more scenario if a user is deleted all his access will be revoked and the user will not be able to call a API for liking the Post. So anyway only valid users will be calling the API.

And for that 1 % case where user still has the access, maintaining the user list at UserLike service will not help as processing the deleted event at the UserLike service can also have a delay.

Now if I really really want to maintain a list at the UserLike or Dislike Service side

first I will subscribe to the list so that I also start getting the events but not processing it

then I will call api for users service to give user to me in batches

after the initial sync I will start processing the events.

Reason of not doing the UserSyncRequest is that all listener to UsersEvent will receive the events which they have already processed.